# preg_match_all crashing/bugging?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Okay, so I have this script that has been the same for at least 3 months now. The code hasn't been modified at all. Nor has my server (VPS) been modified either. But now out of nowhere, started about 24 hours ago, a line in the script is causing the page/script to timeout/crash (white page after about 30 seconds).

The line of code in question is this:

```
$string = preg_match_all('/\[img\]([^\'"\[\]]+)\[\/img\]/is', substr($pag['page_text'], 0, 1024), $matches);
```

If I comment that line out the page loads fine. The thing is that line is critical to the page. Does anyone know why the preg_match_all function would cause a page to crash? Especially since I haven't changed anything on the server or script..

Comment: You may want to add what's in `$pag['page_text']`.

Comment: The preg_match_all is in a function that goes through each row of a returned MySQL query. And it currently returns 6 results that invoke the preg_match_all call, which are here:
http://pastebin.com/m21fe2b55

The thing is, I'm sure the content has nothing to do with preg_match_all failing because it's been the same content for at least a week now.

Comment: I very much doubt the timeout occurs due to preg_match_all(). Are you 100% sure the problem's not on the database end?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the string and the regex capturing might be affecting your memory_limit.